# How to temporarily add more DNS search paths to bash script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, dns

I'm writing a Bash script with a module within that looks up certain host names by short names only.  The problem is that I'm working on an admin box  that communicates with ~20 different environments.  I can only define so many DNS search paths on the box itself (7 I think), so I'm wondering whether there's a way to temporarily set an environment variable at the start of my script that adds in the remaining 13 search paths?

Comment: How does the script look like? Also are you referring to the `search` option from `resolv.conf`?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to `resolv.conf`'s limit.  The integral part of the script is my checking whether a particular hostname is registered in DNS, but I only have the short name.  So I'd run something like `host $1` to check that, but right now it only works on domains that are defined in `resolv.conf`

Comment: Then why not append all possible domains and try them?

Comment: Do you mean append them in `resolv.conf`?  From my understanding, RedHat only checks the first 6 items in there, so it wouldn't matter if I appended all of them. I could be wrong about that though, that's what I was trying to get at in the question

Comment: `for hostname in hostnames; do for domain in domains; do host ${hostname}.${domain}; done; done`

Comment: oh man. that was too simple.  thanks @CristianCiupitu! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for hostname in $hostnames; do
    for domain in $domains; do
        host ${hostname}.${domain}
        # check the result of the command
    done
done
```

If you replace `for domain in $domains` with `for domain in $domains ''` it will also search under the root domain (`.`). This can be useful if there's a fully qualified hostname (e.g. `www.example.net`) in your list.